# How can I manipulate the search input provided by user in react?

Tags: reactjs

I am building an application that fetches a player's details, using the input. But the api only allows fetching the details using **player's id**, hence I have to use another method to first get the id using player's name. But there is some problem  getting the input. I also tried using e.target.value, but it isn't working

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import HLTV from 'hltv';

// Getting player id using this fn.
const getPlayerIdByName = async (text) => {

    return await HLTV.getPlayerByName({ name: text })
        .then(res => res.id)
        // .then(data => console.log(data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

//Getting player stats using id obtained from above
const getPlayerStats = (playerId) => {
    HLTV.getPlayerStats({ id: playerId })
        .then(res => Object.entries(res))

}


const Search = () => {

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [id, setId] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        getPlayerIdByName(name)
            .then(id => setId(id))
    }, [name]);

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setName(name);
        console.log(name)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="player">
                <input type="text" value={name} placeholder="Enter Player's in game name" onChange={onChange} />

                <button type="Submit" defaultValue="Search">Search</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: I have copy-pasted your code but everything seems to be as I am able to get what I have typed in the input but still there was error : `SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: So, now I want to display the contents by calling getPlayerStats( ) function. What is the preferred way of doing this?

Comment: I am not sure about that as I don't know what you are receiving as data and in what format does it come, so I would suggest ask another question based on that but provide more details that's it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refactor your code like this:

The main problem I see, is that you are using `useEffect()` to get the `playerIdByName` every time that `name` changes. Instead, just call that function inside the `onSubmit` handler. And instead of storing the id in state, store your stats instead.

Then, when you have stats in state, you can render them by maping the key value pairs.

```js
import HLTV from 'hltv';

// Getting player id using this fn.
const getPlayerByName = async (text) => await HLTV.getPlayerByName({ name: text });

//Getting player stats using id obtained from above
const getPlayerStats = async (playerId) => await HLTV.getPlayerStats({ id: playerId });

const Search = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [stats, setStats] = useState([]);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };

  const fetchStats = async () => {
    const player = await getPlayerByName(name);
    const stats = await getPlayerStats(player.id);
    const statsEntries = Object.entries(stats);
    setStats(statsEntries);
  };

  const onSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await fetchStats();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} className="player">
        <input
          type="text"
          value={name}
          placeholder="Enter Player's in game name"
          onChange={onChange}
        />

        <button type="Submit" defaultValue="Search">
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
      {stats.length > 0 && (
        <div>
          {stats.map(([key, value]) => (
            <p>
              {key}: {value}
            </p>
          ))}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Search;
```